Frobenius antecedent of a differential module
Let $K$ be an ultrametric complete field of mixed characteristic, and let $F_{\rho}$ be the completion of $K(t)$ with respect to $\rho$-Gauss norm. After Christol and Dwork, for a differential module $(M,\nabla)$ over $(F_\rho,d/dt)$ such that $\|\nabla\|_{sp}<\rho^{-1}$, there exists a unique Frobenius antecedent $(N,\nabla_N)$ of $(M,\nabla)$ (i.e $(N,\nabla_N)$ is a differential module over $(F_{\rho^p},d/dt)$, with $\|\nabla_N\|_{sp}<{(|p|\rho^p)}^{-1}$, and the pull-back of $(N,\nabla_N)$ by the Frobenius is isomorphic to $(M,\nabla)$). Moreover, $\|\nabla\|_{sp}^p=|p|\|\nabla_N\|_{sp}$(i.e. $R_1(N)=R_1(M)^p$).
In the book p-adic differential equations, by Kiran Kedlaya, he proposed a proof of this theorem (Theorem 10.4.2) that seems simpler than the one provided by Christol. However, I have a problem to understand the beginning of the proof.
Let $\zeta_p$ be a $p$th primitive root of the unity, we may assume that $\zeta_p\in K$. For each $m\in\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ he defined an $K$-linear endomorphism on $M$ by:
$$\zeta_p^m(v)=\sum_{l=0}^\infty\frac{(\zeta_p^mt-t)^l}{l!}\nabla^l(v),$$
and for each $j\in\{0,\dots,p-1\}$
$$P_j(v)=\frac{1}{p}\sum_{i=0}^{p-1}\zeta_p^{-ij}\zeta_p^i(v).$$
Why it is claimed that $P_j$ are $F_{\rho^p}$-linear?

Given $f(t)\in F_\rho$ and $v\in M$, we just need to prove
$$\zeta_p^m(f(t)v)=f(\zeta_p^m t)\zeta_p^m(v).$$
We observe that
$$f(\zeta_p^mt)=\zeta_p^m(f(t))=\sum_{i=0}^\infty\frac{(\zeta_p^mt-t)^i}{i!}\frac{d}{dt}^i(f(t)).$$
Using the Leibniz rule we obtain
$$\zeta_p^m(f(t)v)=\zeta_p^m(f(t))\zeta_p^m(v)=f(\zeta_p^m t)\zeta_p^m(v).$$
Hence, for all $m\in\{1,\dots,p-1\}$, $\zeta_p^m:M\to M$ is $F_{\rho^p}$-linear, then so is for each $P_j$.
